# Kotlin-How can i remove a fragment in activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I want to create a fragment in a activity an after doing some work for me , remove it .

Code :

```
class Payment_Activity : AppCompatActivity() {

 lateinit var btnincrese : Button

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.payment_activity)



  val tenbtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.ten)

  btnincrese = findViewById(R.id.btn_increase)

  btnincrese.setOnClickListener {

  fragover()
  
   makepayment(10000)


}
```

```
  private fun makepayment(amount: Long) {


        val purchase = ZarinPal.getPurchase(this)

        val payment: PaymentRequest = ZarinPal.getSandboxPaymentRequest()
        payment.merchantID = getString(R.string.MerchantId)
        payment.amount = amount
        payment.isZarinGateEnable(true)
        payment.description = getString(R.string.incresemoney)
        payment.setCallbackURL("returnfromzarinpal://mivebaranapp")



        purchase.startPayment(payment) {


                status, authority, paymentGatewayUri, intent ->

            if (status == 100) {


                remover()
                
                startActivity(intent)
           

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(
                    this,
                    "خطایی در برقراری ارتباط با درگاه رخ داده ، لطفا دوباره امتحان کنید",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()


}
```

```
fun fragover (){


    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.rl_payment , OverFragment())
        .commit()


}
```

```
   fun remover() {

       supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
           .remove(OverFragment())
           .commit()
       

   }

    }
```

why when i call function remover in makepayment function, the fragment (Over Fragment ) not removed .
I searched some in stack and other sites but nothing helpful .

why is wrong with my code ?

is there a better way to do this ?

thank's for help .

Answer (score 0):

this code does work for me .

```
    private fun clearfragment(){

        val fragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments
        for (frag in fragment){

            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit()
        }

        supportFragmentManager.popBackStack(null , FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE)
    }
```

I hope be useful